# How can in interpret the SVM summary on e1071 package in R?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, libsvm, e1071

I don't know how to interpret the svm summary outputs in R. I show you the reproducible code below. 
   data <- read.csv(file.choose (), header = TRUE, sep=';')
     set.seed(1234)
     splitIndex <- createDataPartition(
                      dati[,outcomeName], 
                      p = .75, list = FALSE, times = 1)
     trainDF <- dati[ splitIndex,]

```
 testDF  <- dati[-splitIndex,]

 model_svm <- svm(Y~.,data = trainDF) 

> model_svm_test <- svm(Y~.,data = testDF)

> summary(model_svm)


THESE ARE THE TWO SUMMARY OUTPUTS. THE FIRST ONE FOR TRAIN AND THE SECOND ONE FOR TEST
Call:
svm(formula = Y ~ ., data = trainDF)


Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.0625 
    epsilon:  0.1 


Number of Support Vectors:  1886





> summary(model_svm_test)

Call:
svm(formula = Y ~ ., data = testDF)


Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.0625 
    epsilon:  0.1 


Number of Support Vectors:  799
```

Comment: What do you *not* understand here, after you've reviewed the documentation?

Comment: Regarding SVM type you can read this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237382/difference-between-the-types-of-svm